# Jade for-loop with #{self.variable} NOT fixed List

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

It must be an extremely special case i´m asking for, since there are over 1000 Pages of the standard for/each concept of jade:

```
each value, index in [1,2,3]
  li= val + ':' + index
```

But I want to use my own dynamical list (from outside), e.g.

```
#{self.trolls}
```

This does not work:

```
each value, index in #{self.trolls}
  li= val + ':' + index
```

Error thrown: *Unexpected token ILLEGAL*

Any suggestions?

I also tried:

```
- trolls= #{self.trolls}
```

Throws error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.trolls` is available to the jade script, `#{}` is only for outputting it.

You can simply just use

```
each value, index in self.trolls
```